# Generating DDL CQL create table scripts using spring-data-cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

For an application, I am managing Cassandra table definitions in a json file. Definition is something like array of partition key, array of clustering key, array of all the columns then array of column definitions, each column definition has column name and its data type. We were asked to create a tool which can read this json file and create a file containing CQL DDL create table scripts.

```
{
   "tableDefinitions":[
       {
         "tableName":"employee"
         "partitionKeyColumns":["department"],
         "clusteringKeyColumns":["name"],
         "columns":["id","address"]
       }
   ],
   "columnDefinitions":[
       {"name":"id","type":"text"},
       {"name":"name","type":"text"},
       {"name":"department","type":"text"},
       {"name":"address","type":"text"}
   ]
}
```

To achieve this, we used CreateTableSpecification. To set the column in this, method we have is -

```
public T column(String name, DataType type) {
    return this.column(CqlIdentifier.of(name), type);
}
```

where DataType is com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.

Before calling this method, I convert string dataType to com.datastax.driver.core.DataType. It was fine till we just had primitive data types on our columns. When we changed data type of one of our column to set, we were in trouble because there is no way available to change this string to corresponding com.datastax.driver.core.DataType. Because if you check this class, it doesn't expose SET datatype.

I am unable to convert string set into com.datastax.driver.core.DataType

Any other way to generate DDL create table CQL script on the fly when you have table definitions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SchemaBuilder](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.7/com/datastax/driver/core/schemabuilder/SchemaBuilder.html) from the underlying DataStax Java driver. And `DataType` type has corresponding [methods](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.7/com/datastax/driver/core/DataType.html#set-com.datastax.driver.core.DataType-) for sets/maps/lists - you only need to pass correct nested type to it...

Something like this (not tested):

```java
String cql = SchemaBuilder.create("ks", "tbl")
  .addPartitionKey("id", DataType.cint)
  .addColumn("value", DataType.set(DataType.cint))
  .buildInternal();
```

Comment: Problem I have is to resolve DataType from String value. Suppose I have set<text>, now how to get it's corresponding DataType. And this is not the only datatype, it can be anything. I am looking for an API - public DataType getDataType(String dataType)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I had to write boilerplate code to achieve that.